# SLURM display the stdout and stderr of an unfinished job

Tags: lsf, slurm

I used to use a server with LSF but now I just transitioned to one with SLURM.

What is the equivalent command of bpeek (for LSF) in SLURM?

bpeek 
bpeek Displays the stdout and stderr output of an unfinished job

I couldn't find the documentation anywhere.  If you have some good references for SLURM, please let me know as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might also want to have a look at the [`sattach`](http://slurm.schedmd.com/sattach.html) command.

Comment: sattach doesn't believe in my jobid (`Invalid job id specified`). The id I specify is identical to that output by `squeue`, though I'm not sure what 'step' to use. I don't use `srun` in my script, is that relevant? I ran my job with `sbatch` and a bash script that has a few slurm parameters, loads a few modules, `cd` and then runs a single python program.

Comment: Apparently it's possible to have different steps in your batch file, drevicko.  I'm not sure what steps are, but doing `<jobid>.0` allowed this to work for me.  (I guess not setting up steps means you are at step 0 by default.)

Answer (score 8):

I just learned that in SLURM there is no need to do bpeek to check the current standard output and standard error since they are printed in running time to the files specified for the stdout and stderr.

Comment: Not in my (admittedly a little limited) experience, though perhaps it's buffered.

Comment: I'd add that you can use `scontrol show job <jobid>` to figure out where the standard output and standard error is written to. Useful if you have many jobs and can't easily track which job id writes to which output.

Comment: In my case there is no StdOut info in `scontrol show job my_job_id`. I guess that means it isn't saving it anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround that I use. It mimics the `bpeek` functionality from LSF

Create a file bpeek.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# take as input an argument - slurm job id - and save it into a variable
jobid=$1
# run scontrol show job $jobid and save the output into a variable
#find the string that starts with StdOut= and save it into a variable without the StdOut= part
stdout=$(scontrol show job $jobid | grep StdOut= | sed 's/StdOut=//')
#show last 10 rows of the file if no argument 2 is given
nrows=${2:-10}
tail -f -n $nrows $stdout
```

Then you can use it:
`sh bpeek.sh JOBID NROWS(optional)`

Or add an alias to `~/.bashrc` file:
`alias bpeek="sh ~/bpeek.sh $1 $2"`

and then use it:
`bpeek JOBID NROWS(optional)`