# Get stdout/stderr from a slurm job at runtime

Tags: stdout, slurm

I have a batch file to send a job with `sbatch`.
The contents of the batch file is

```
# Setting the proper SBATCH variables 
...
#SBATCH --error="test_slurm-%j.err"
#SBATCH --output="test_slurm-%j.out"
...

WORKDIR=.
echo "Run 1"
${WORKDIR}/test_slurm
echo "Run 2"
${WORKDIR}/test_slurm
```

File `test_slurm-%j.out` is sometimes appended with output only after each of the lines is finished.
For instance, the output of the first instance of `test_slurm` would not be dumped into `test_slurm-%j.out` until `test_slurm` finishes.

**Is there any way of having stdout/stderr "flushed" at runtime, so I can check file `test_slurm-%j.out` to monitor execution?**

As per
[How to change how frequently SLURM updates the output file (stdout)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170763/how-to-change-how-frequently-slurm-updates-the-output-file-stdout)
and
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe
I tried with

```
stdbuf -oL -eL ${WORKDIR}/test_slurm
stdbuf -o0 -e0 ${WORKDIR}/test_slurm
stdbuf -o1 -e1 ${WORKDIR}/test_slurm
unbuffer ${WORKDIR}/test_slurm
```

None of this worked.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062153/slurm-display-the-stdout-and-stderr-of-an-unfinished-job) does not seem to provide the answer.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious but is working directory is shared among compute nodes?

Comment: Probably not slurm's doing. I don't believe it messes with buffering, rather it simply does whatever the script tells it to. There isn't really enough information here to go on. Try running the batch file without slurm and observe the buffering behavior.